# Prove $\exists x,y \in A$ st $\mu(A \cap (x,y))>c(x-y)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$ and $A$ be a measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}$ with positive measure. Prove for any $c\in (0,1),$ $\exists x,y \in A$ st $\mu(A \cap (x,y))>c(x-y)$.

I saw the similar problem where it had slight modification, it says Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}$ and $A$ be a measurable subset of $\Bbb{R}$ with positive measure. Prove for any $c\in (0,1),\exists$ an interval $I$ st $\mu(A \cap I)>c \mu(I)$.
I'm not able to modify the proof since here $I$ may have endpoints which are not in $A$.

Comment: The end points have Lebesgue measure zero, yes? So they shouldn't affect the proof.

Comment: @jdods is correct. The statement you provide is exactly the same as the statement you want to prove.

Comment: Here I've to find an interval inside $A$ rather than any interval.

Comment: I take it should be $y-x$ as well otherwise there is nothing to prove?

Comment: This seems funny. What if A is an interval? Then it's intersection with any sub interval is the sub interval. Thus retaining full measure of the sub interval, so multiplication by $c<1$ doesn't work. What am I missing?